# В чем разница и как правильно прописать стили в визуальном редакторе Битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс

Встала задача прописать свои стили в визуальном редакторе сайта на Битриксе. Погуглив, нашла такую логику действия.

1. Прописываем в файле styles.css стиль, который хотим добавить в визуальный редактор.
2. Чтобы стиль отображался в меню, пишем в файле .styles.php

   ```
   <?
   return array (
   "example" => array(
          "tag" => 'p', 
          "title" => "название стиля", 
          "html" => '<span style="border: 2px solid red;color: #ff0000; padding: 4px;">Пример</span>')
   );
   ?>
   ```

После этого собственный стиль отобразится в меню визуального редактора Битрикс.

У нас же на сайте это реализовано иначе. В файле .styles.php прописано таким образом:

```
<?
return array (
);
?>
```

При этом свои стили не отображаются в меню редактора, а их требуется вызывать в редактируемом поле через правую кнопку мыши "Свойства". Попробовала сделать как в способе,который описала выше, но ничего не вышло. По прежнему в самом меню визуального редактора, добавленные стили не отображаются.

В чем причина? Какой способ реализации лучше?